# How to iterate over two lists?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I am trying to do something in pyGTk where I build a list of HBoxes:

```
self.keyvalueboxes = []
for keyval in range(1,self.keyvaluelen):
    self.keyvalueboxes.append(gtk.HBox(False, 5))
```

But I then want to run over the list and assign A text entry & a label into each one both of which are stored in a list.

Comment: Is this what you want or are you looking for something else?

Comment: What you posted was great. Not quite what I was looking for but I used it to fix the issue! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your list are of equal length use zip

```
>>> x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> z = zip(x,y)
>>> z
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
>>> for l in z: print l[0], l[1]
... 
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
>>>
```

Comment: @Fergus Barker: Great then :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip. It lets you iterate over two lists at the same time.